# ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve './Features/Assignment/assignment' in '/Users/temp/Desktop/myfirstreact/src'

Tags: reactjs

[image: This is the folder structure of my react application]

and I am importing the assignment.js into the App.js.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change assignment to assignment. or please rename the namespace of the assignment. to assignment